# Let $f$ be entire such that $f(0) = 1$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1 + |z|^{3/2}~~~\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire such that $f(0) = 1$ and $$|f(z)| \leq  1 + |z|^{3/2}~~~\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$

Show that $f(z) = 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

I have done everything and have shown that $f(z) = az+1$ by using Cauchy Integrals formula and ML formula on $f^{''}(z)$

However, i cannot find out how to show that $a = 0$ so that my answer can be $f(z) = 1$ for all $z$?

Any ideas?

Comment: Set $z=\epsilon>0$. The given inequality becomes $1+|a|\epsilon \le 1 +\epsilon^\frac32.$ From there you conclude that $a=0$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro But how can you set a arbitrary $z$ to be $\epsilon >0$?

Comment: The inequality you found is true for all $z\in\mathbb C$. Right? So, in particular, it is true if $z$ is a positive real number. For convenience, let $\epsilon>0$ denote such a number. This $\epsilon$ must verify the inequality $1+|a|\epsilon\le 1+\epsilon^\frac32$, which implies that $|a|\le \epsilon^\frac12$, and this can only hold if $|a|=0$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you! i got it now!